# Can grub modules be embedded in the grub binary?

Tags: grub2

Grub has similar concept of modules like the Linux kernel.
They are a bunch of precompiled files which usually live at `boot/grub/x86_64-efi/<module_name>.mod` on the rootfs.

The module needs to be loaded before it can be used. "used" means that you can you can run a particular new command in `grub.cfg`. A way you install a module is having a `insmod <module_name>`.

Is it possible to embed a grub module withing the grub binary instead of having the modules living on the rootfs?

Answer (score 1):

When you install grub, you can indicate `grub-install --modules=…` and get some modules preloaded.

You can also use `grub-probe …` which gives you the modules needed to access a given directory.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hoping to understand what does that turn into exactly. Will it just copy the `.mod` files to the EFI partition?

Comment: This depends : on an old MBR system, there are is space after the boot sector and before the first partition (30ko). On an EFI boot, a `grubx64.efi` file is created.

Comment: That's the boot-loader binary`grubx64.efi`. I'm trying to understand if modules can also live within the bootloader binary or they always exist as a separate `.mod` file.

Comment: The `grubx64.efi` is typically made by a low level command : `grub-mkimage -p /boot/grub -O x86_64-efi -c grub-pre.cfg -o /tmp/grubx64.efi luks2 part_gpt cryptodisk gcry_rijndael pbkdf2 gcry_sha256 ext2` Then it embeds the partition table handling, filesystem and other things needed to load your favorite kernel.

Comment: The modules are literally included within the `grubx64.efi` binary file. In case of Secure Boot, this is essential, as anything that loads program code without performing Secure Boot signature checks would be classifiable as a "Secure Boot circumvention device". The modules are ELF binaries, but when included, a single signature on the resulting `.efi` binary covers them all.